# What happens when a for loop has no increment expression in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, decrement

**I found that I had a return statement inside my loop. Thanks for the help anyways everyone.**

I have come across a for loop in Java that does not have an increment/decrement expression. As a matter of fact, my IDE tells me that the expression is dead code.

Loop without the increment/decrement expression:

```
for(int i = 5; i!=0;)
  //Do something...
```

Then whenever I try to add `i--` like so:

```
for(int i = 5; i!=0; i--)
```

My IDE tells me that `i--` is dead code, which confuses me, as I do not see how I will change. So my question is, how does this loop work in Java? Is this an infinite loop? Does the JVM decrement `i` on it's own? Etc...

Minimal Example:

```
for(int i=10; i!=0;i--)
  //Do something...
```

Complete:

```
public void methodName(int number){
  for(int i = number; i!=0; i--)
    //Do something...
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? Judging that one line on its own, removing `i--` is wrong. It would cause an infinite loop--unless `i` is elsewhere modified inside the loop body.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes. One moment...

Comment: If you want an infinite loop, just use `while (true)` or whatever.

Comment: My IDE finds `for(int i = 5; i!=0; i--){}` a perfectly fine loop.

Comment: @JohnKugelman No. Eclipse is actually told me that the `i--` is dead code. Specifically that. When I remove it, I would assume that there would be an infinite loop, but when I add the 'i--', eclipse will say that the code is "dead" and fixes are either removing or adding `SuppressWarnings 'unused' to methodName`

Comment: Please fill in the code that you've labelled "//Do something..." - that is the bit of code that matters the most! It certainly contains something that would make the `i--` dead code. Without the for-loop body, the `i--` certainly is not dead.

Comment: Do you call the method "methodName" anywhere ?

Comment: @dreamcrash Not yet, but that wouldn't cause a warning. It's public.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Ok. One moment... But I will say now that I don't think it modifies the loop or i in any way.

Comment: By the way, you seem to have misunderstood the term "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example". It means _one piece_ of code that is, at once, both minimal and complete. (And verifiable, which means we should ideally be able to compile & run it.)

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Oh. Sorry about that.

Comment: I found the problem. I had a return line inside the for loop. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should need to work for all i's which are lesser than 5.

So you will need to write the for loop as:

```
for(int i = 5; i>=0; i--)
```

And this will be an infinite loop:

```
for(int i = 5; i!=0;){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Since it will keep working for all i's that are not equal to 0.

Comment: I know that that would work, but I wanted to know specifically what a loop without the increment/decrement expression would do. Also, one may need their loop to run infinitely if the i is less than zero, and `!=` seems like a good way to do it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with have `i!=0`.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer:

```
for (int i = 5; i != 0;) {
    System.out.println(i);
} // ,
```

Will output the integer 5 forever.

It's the equivalent of:

```
int i = 5;
while (i != 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

It outputs 5 forever because `i` is **always** 5 and `i` is **always** different than 0. In order to escape the loop, you have to explicitly update the value of `i` until it holds the value of 0.